# How would i fix this error in creating a genesis block

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, pycrypto

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RAC\crypto\...\blockchain.py", line 178, in <module>
    blockchain = Blockchain()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\RAC\crypto\...\blockchain.py", line 49, in __init__       
    self.chain = [self.create_genesis_block(0)]
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Blockchain.create_genesis_block() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

with code looking like this

```
class Blockchain:
    def __init__(self):
        self.chain = [self.create_genesis_block(0)]
        self.difficulty = 4
        self.nodes = dict()
        self.replicated_nodes = dict()
        self.coin_ledger = dict()

    def create_genesis_block(self):
        return Block("Genesis Block", "0", coin)
```

ive tried adding other arguments but as i am new to this, i havent been able to figure it out myself properly

Comment: What do you intend the `0` in `self.create_genesis_block(0)` to mean? How should your code know to handle the argument you've supplied?

Comment: (Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! Good places to start are the [tour] and [ask]. Please also read about what we expect of a [MRE] when looking for debugging help.)

Comment: thank you but what do you mean? im sorry ive been using an ai to help me create this code im about to launch so i need all the help i can get

Comment: ...Well, that's alarming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def create_genesis_block(self):` doesn't take a parameter, maybe you meant:

```
def create_genesis_block(self, block_num):
        return Block("Genesis Block", block_num, coin)
```

or

```
@staticmethod 
def create_genesis_block(block_num):
        return Block("Genesis Block", block_num, coin)
```

Comment: Thank you this helped and all i had to do was remove the coin part as well and kept the second block_num to 0

Answer (score -1):

when you use the self constructor, you need to initialize the class, try

```
instanse = Blockchain()
instanse.create_genesis_block()
```